# Is this grammatically correct? omitting "and"

Tags: grammar

It is terrifying when I see people demolishing cultural sites and monuments, "and" recording and posting them online.

Is it ok if I omit the second "and"?
Will it still make sense?

Comment: The "them" in your sentence refers to "cultural sites and monuments", thus the sentence does not make much sense with or without the "and".

Comment: If you want to avoid the repetition you could say 'then' instead of the second  'and' giving "...cultural sites and monuments the posting recordings of the destruction on line." This isn't a universal answer but would work here because the posting happens after the destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greybeard says, in your sentence people are posting the cultural sites and monuments online. They're *not*. They are posting clips, films or movie clips. You need to rearrange it.

I think this would be the most precise way to say it:

> It is terrifying to see, posted online, recordings people have made of
> themselves demolishing cultural sites and monuments.

Or *possibly*:

> It is terrifying to see recordings people have made of themselves
> demolishing cultural sites and monuments being posted online.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful.___How about this "It is terrifying when I see people demolish cultural sites, record their act of violence and post it online." Is it acceptable?

Comment: Not really. Is it terrifying for *us* when you see that? Really? "It is terrifying to see" was clear: "It is terrifying when I see" is not. What "act of violence" are they recording? Shouldn't it be *acts*? What is **it** in "and post it..."? Why aren't you content with one of the suggestions above?